# Is it possible to get features from one layer within the bounding box of other layer?

Tags: geoserver, layers, http-post

I have 2 seperate layers say: water bodies layer, land layer from different sources but for the same location. as shown below:
[image]

No I want to use the bounding box of water bodies layer and get the featureID's of the 2 features in land layer.

I am using geoserver for testing. Is this possible using HTTP POST request? as my wfs doesnot support HTTP GET request. Please provide with any examples for better understanding.

Answer (score 3):

First you need to add the querylayer module ([instructions here](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html#installing-the-querylayer-module)), then you can make use of the filter functions querySingle, queryCollection and collectGeometries ([see reference](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/querylayer/index.html#function-reference)) in your filter in exactly the same way as any other filter.

As a post request you will need something like:

```
<wfs:GetFeature xmlns:wfs="http://www.opengis.net/wfs"
                   xmlns:sf="http://www.openplans.org/spearfish"
                   xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
                   service="WFS" version="1.0.0">
     <wfs:Query typeName="sf:bugsites">
       <ogc:Filter>
         <ogc:Intersects>
           <ogc:PropertyName>the_geom</ogc:PropertyName>
           <ogc:Function name="querySingle">
              <ogc:Literal>sf:restricted</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>the_geom</ogc:Literal>
              <ogc:Literal>cat = 3</ogc:Literal>
           </ogc:Function>
         </ogc:Intersects>
       </ogc:Filter>
     </wfs:Query>
   </wfs:GetFeature>
```

This fetches only the bug sites overlapping the restricted area whose category is 3.

Comment: Thank you... That's a good start for cross layer filtering..

Comment: Hi, Can the cross layer filtering applied on non geoserver layers? and layers from completely different WFS sources?

Comment: No, you would need a custom WPS job for that sort of thing